# Find out which process opens a bunch of mysterious connections in Linux (Azure)

Tags: linux, azure, connection

When stress testing our server I see a lot of (200+) open HTTPS connections to mysterious ip in Ubuntu 16.04 running in Azure. This ip belongs to Microsoft.

- This ip does not belong to any of our machines nor the services we're
  using
- When shutting down the server process, connections still keep appearing but only 4-5 at a time compared to 200+ when stress testing and server process enabled. Server is not running any other services (fresh install from Azure + our process)
- No matter what I try to do, I cannot see the process where these connections are coming from (netstat, lsof, etc. running as root)

netstat prints a lot of these

```
$ sudo netstat -p | grep 52.239.137.70
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.6:59202          52.239.137.70:https     TIME_WAIT   -
...
```

When trying to open this ip in a web browser (HTTP or HTTPS), you see this error

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code>InvalidUri</code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">
        The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server. RequestId...
    </message>
</error>
```

So I'm guessing this is somehow connected to Azure Blob service, since when googling the error message you get a bunch forum posts troubleshooting blobs.

I have troubleshooted this for two days and cannot find an answer. I am worried that this will cause problems when under high load in production because when testing with small amounts of clients you still see hundreds of these mystery connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem. It seems that uninstalling LinuxDiagnostic Azure extension stops the connections from appearing. Associated process (mdsd) also used large amounts of memory.